# Overwrite table in BigQuery with java

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to periodically erase all data from a table and start from scratch.  From what I have read here, the best way to do that is to delete and then create the table.  I have tried that and the resulting table does not have any data in it that I add immediately after the create.

Basically I do (in java):

```
TableId myTable = TableId.of("MyDataset", "MyTable");
Table table = bigQuery.getTable(myTable);
table.delete();
TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(myTable, definition).build();
table = bigQuery.create(tableInfo);
List<RowToInsert> initialRows = new ArrayList<RowToInsert>();
... add about 5 rows to initialRows
table.insert(initialRows);
```

I have no problem if I don't do the delete and instead create only new tables. Also, I am limited to using java only for this.

Any ideas what I need to do differently?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is it not working?

Comment: Correct, After the insert I see 0 rows in the table.

Comment: After a bit more checking, it seems like this is expected behavior.  If you have data in a streaming buffer and delete the table, the streaming buffer is not deleted. Subsequent inserts go to that same buffer which seems to eventually catch up with the delete and all data is discarded.

So I will work on ways around that.

Answer (score 0):

Although that being expected behaviour, maybe something can still be done:

```
bool check;
while(check ){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            try {
                table1 = bigquery.getTable(myTable);
                out1.println( "*** deleting table: "+table2.getTableId().toString()+ " ***" );  

            } catch (Exception e) {
                check = false;
                out1.println("***     table DELETED     ***     "); 
                //break;
            }

        }
```

And then to make it sure check if the rows have been added and then if not try again with exponential backoff (for example).